# Bug or feature: no focusOwner if control added to scene directly?

Tags: java, focus, javafx-8

Just noticed that a scene with a "bare" control as root (in the example below the control is a TableView) doesn't have a focusOwner initially. In fact, there is no focusOwner at all (scene's property doesn't fire). Without focusOwner, the control is not reachable via keyboard. Not a very realistic real-world scenario, concededly, but anyway ...

Adding the control to any Parent and then setting that parent as root transfers focus to the control - which is what I expect always.

What's wrong - my expectation or the behaviour?

```
/**
 * Table doesn't have focus initially if not wrapped into a Parent.
 * jdk 8u60b5 (didn't try others)
 */
public class TableInitialCellEdit extends Application {

    ObservableList<MenuItem> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new MenuItem("some"),
            new MenuItem("dummy"),
            new MenuItem("data")
            );

    private Parent getContent() {
        TableView<MenuItem> table = new TableView<>(data);
        table.setEditable(true);
        TableColumn<MenuItem, String> text = new TableColumn<>("Text");
        text.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text"));
        text.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        table.getColumns().addAll(text);
        // focus transfered to table if contained in a pane
        // return new Pane(table);
        // focus not transfered to table if contained directly in the scene 
        return table;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(getContent());
        scene.focusOwnerProperty().addListener((s, old, value) -> System.out.println(value));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle(VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the documentation of [Node.requestFocus()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#requestFocus--), I would consider this behaviour a bug.

My guess is the bug lies in the method `.com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal.TabOrderHelper#getFirstTargetNode(Parent)`

```
public static Node getFirstTargetNode(Parent p) {
    if (p == null || isDisabledOrInvisible(p)) return null;
    final ParentTraversalEngine impl_traversalEngine = p.getImpl_traversalEngine();
    if (impl_traversalEngine!= null && impl_traversalEngine.canTraverse()) {
        Node selected = impl_traversalEngine.selectFirst();
        if (selected != null) {
            return selected;
        }
    }
    List<Node> parentsNodes = p.getChildrenUnmodifiable();
    for (Node n : parentsNodes) {
        if (isDisabledOrInvisible(n)) continue;
        final ParentTraversalEngine parentEngine = n instanceof Parent ? ((Parent)n).getImpl_traversalEngine() : null;
        if (parentEngine != null ? parentEngine.isParentTraversable() : n.isFocusTraversable()) {
            return n;
        }
        if (n instanceof Parent) {
            Node result = getFirstTargetNode((Parent)n);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If I read this correctly, it recurses down the hierarchy of p to find a suitable Node to focus. p in this case is the table. It recurses through its childrens children but never finds a Node to focus until it return null. The problem might be, that this method never considers to return p itself.

Comment: +1 interesting dig-down into really nasty code (shouldn't do any ad hoc traversal in a static helper but abstract properly in a traversalEngine)  And agree: not considering itself as a valid return node looks like the real problem - at least for the very highest level, that is the SceneTraversalEngine.